# What means -Ron in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

i have the bash script to execute in xcode to find at compile time if any image is missing in assets.
i am trying to read it and stuck on a point, i have done google but could not find satisfactory answer. please guide me about it, the part of script is

```
ERROR_LOCATION=$(grep -Ron "\[UIImage imageNamed:\s*@\"$1\"\s*\]" $PROJECT_NAME)
```

grep is an linux command

**-Ron** is confused word not found what is it mean please explain it

Comment: Did you try reading `man grep`?

Comment: These are the flags of grep command. Your first help is `grep --help` or `man grep`. Where `R` means recursive. `o` means print only the matched ones, `n` means print the line number of the matches as well.

Comment: PS thanks for quick response, now i got it that multiple flags can be used as combination

Comment: Check out [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+-Ron+%22%5C%5BUIImage+imageNamed%3A%5Cs%2A%40%5C%22%241%5C%22%5Cs%2A%5C%5D%22+%24PROJECT_NAME). It'll automatically tell you what flags and shell features are.

Comment: excellent site to get help to read script thanks

Answer (score 0):

please read the manpage from grep here: [LINK](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

**-R**

**--dereference-recursive**

For each directory operand, read and process all files in that directory, recursively, following all symbolic links.

**-o**

**--only-matching**

Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines, with each such part on a separate output line. Output lines use the same delimiters as input, and delimiters are null bytes if -z (--null-data) is also used (see Other Options).

**-n**

**--line-number**

Prefix each line of output with the 1-based line number within its input file. (-n is specified by POSIX.)